# Optimize SQL query performance (Oracle 12)

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I would like to optimize join between following tables, please advise.

**Additional questions:**

1. Is better to use all indexes between all tables
2. Is better to use
   syntax FROM A join B on A.ID = B.ID (faster)?
3. Which where condition
   will be handled first (optimizer takse care about best joining)?

   **Please tell me some tips how to optimize.**

Table rows count:

- inv.mtl_material_transactions = 17.466.581
- inv.mtl_transaction_lot_numbers = 13.680.350
- gme.gme_material_details    = 5.302.282
- gme.gme_batch_header = 790.828
- inv.mtl_system_items_b = 516.148
- GMD.fm_matl_dtl = 280.056

See table's indexes:

```
COLUMN_NAME TABLE_NAME
ITEM_ID FM_MATL_DTL
LINE_TYPE   FM_MATL_DTL
FORMULA_ID  FM_MATL_DTL
FORMULALINE_ID  FM_MATL_DTL
FORMULA_ID  FM_MATL_DTL
LINE_TYPE   FM_MATL_DTL
LINE_NO FM_MATL_DTL
ORGANIZATION_ID GME_BATCH_HEADER
BATCH_NO    GME_BATCH_HEADER
BATCH_STATUS    GME_BATCH_HEADER
BATCH_CLOSE_DATE    GME_BATCH_HEADER
BATCH_ID    GME_BATCH_HEADER
ORGANIZATION_ID GME_BATCH_HEADER
BATCH_NO    GME_BATCH_HEADER
BATCH_TYPE  GME_BATCH_HEADER
ORGANIZATION_ID GME_MATERIAL_DETAILS
INVENTORY_ITEM_ID   GME_MATERIAL_DETAILS
LINE_TYPE   GME_MATERIAL_DETAILS
BATCH_ID    GME_MATERIAL_DETAILS
PHANTOM_ID  GME_MATERIAL_DETAILS
MATERIAL_DETAIL_ID  GME_MATERIAL_DETAILS
BATCH_ID    GME_MATERIAL_DETAILS
LINE_NO GME_MATERIAL_DETAILS
LINE_TYPE   GME_MATERIAL_DETAILS
INVENTORY_ITEM_ID   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_DATE    MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
COSTED_FLAG MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_GROUP_ID    MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
PARENT_TRANSACTION_ID   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_SET_ID  MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
PM_COST_COLLECTED   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
PM_COST_COLLECTOR_GROUP_ID  MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
COMPLETION_TRANSACTION_ID   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_ACTION_ID   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_SOURCE_TYPE_ID  MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_DATE    MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
PICK_SLIP_NUMBER    MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
MOVE_ORDER_LINE_ID  MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
PICKING_LINE_ID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
RCV_TRANSACTION_ID  MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_SOURCE_ID   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_DATE    MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
PROJECT_ID  MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TO_PROJECT_ID   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
SOURCE_PROJECT_ID   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSFER_TRANSACTION_ID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
INVOICED_FLAG   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_SOURCE_TYPE_ID  MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_ACTION_ID   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
OPM_COSTED_FLAG MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_EXTRACTED   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRX_SOURCE_LINE_ID  MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
XML_DOCUMENT_ID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
SUBINVENTORY_CODE   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_DATE    MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
VENDOR_LOT_NUMBER   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_DATE    MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
SHIPMENT_NUMBER MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
ACCT_PERIOD_ID  MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_SOURCE_TYPE_ID  MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_DATE    MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_SOURCE_NAME MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_ACTION_ID   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_DATE    MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_ID  MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_ACTION_ID   MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_SOURCE_TYPE_ID  MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
TRANSACTION_ID  MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
SEGMENT1    MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
PLANNER_CODE    MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
WEB_STATUS  MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
CUSTOMER_ORDER_ENABLED_FLAG MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
SERVICE_ITEM_FLAG   MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
VENDOR_WARRANTY_FLAG    MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
USAGE_ITEM_FLAG MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
WIP_SUPPLY_LOCATOR_ID   MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
BASE_ITEM_ID    MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
STYLE_ITEM_ID   MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
EAM_ITEM_TYPE   MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
DESCRIPTION MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE  MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
AUTO_CREATED_CONFIG_FLAG    MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
WH_UPDATE_DATE  MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ITEM_CATALOG_GROUP_ID   MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
CATALOG_STATUS_FLAG MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
PRODUCT_FAMILY_ITEM_ID  MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
COMMS_NL_TRACKABLE_FLAG MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
BUYER_ID    MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
INVENTORY_ITEM_ID   MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B
TRANSACTION_ID  MTL_TRANSACTION_LOT_NUMBERS
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_TRANSACTION_LOT_NUMBERS
TRANSACTION_DATE    MTL_TRANSACTION_LOT_NUMBERS
LOT_NUMBER  MTL_TRANSACTION_LOT_NUMBERS
INVENTORY_ITEM_ID   MTL_TRANSACTION_LOT_NUMBERS
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_TRANSACTION_LOT_NUMBERS
TRANSACTION_SOURCE_ID   MTL_TRANSACTION_LOT_NUMBERS
PRODUCT_CODE    MTL_TRANSACTION_LOT_NUMBERS
PRODUCT_TRANSACTION_ID  MTL_TRANSACTION_LOT_NUMBERS
SERIAL_TRANSACTION_ID   MTL_TRANSACTION_LOT_NUMBERS
TRANSACTION_ID  MTL_TRANSACTION_LOT_NUMBERS
ORGANIZATION_ID MTL_TRANSACTION_LOT_NUMBERS
```

Query which I created:

```
SELECT 
gbh.batch_no,
gbh.batch_id,
msi.segment1 as ITEM,
--msi.description,
lot.lot_number as LOT,
gmd.line_type,
msi.inventory_item_id
,fmd.attribute1 as SIGNIFICANT_ITEM
--,msi.inventory_item_id||lot.lot_number as THING_ID
FROM 
gme.gme_batch_header gbh,
gme.gme_material_details gmd,
inv.mtl_material_transactions mmt,
inv.mtl_system_items_b msi,
inv.mtl_transaction_lot_numbers lot
,GMD.fm_matl_dtl fmd
WHERE 1=1
--AND gmd.line_type = -1 
AND gbh.batch_id = gmd.batch_id 
AND gbh.organization_id = 1509
AND gbh.formula_id = fmd.formula_id
AND msi.inventory_item_id = fmd.inventory_item_id
AND msi.organization_id = fmd.organization_id
AND gmd.organization_id = gbh.organization_id 
AND gmd.organization_id = msi.organization_id
AND mmt.inventory_item_id = msi.inventory_item_id
AND mmt.trx_source_line_id = gmd.material_detail_id
AND mmt.transaction_source_id = gmd.batch_id 
AND mmt.transaction_id = lot.transaction_id
AND lot.TRANSACTION_SOURCE_ID = gbh.Batch_Id
AND lot.organization_id = mmt.organization_id
AND lot.inventory_item_id = mmt.inventory_item_id
```

Comment: Proper `JOIN` syntax makes no difference performance wise, but is still recommended.

Comment: Could you share with us the reason for optimization? Are you experiencing long response time? If so, could you provide some additional information like: what are the sizes of the tables, how long takes for the query to complete, how are the tables indexed, etc., etc., etc...

Comment: By the way, there are many things you could do to ease the reading of your question that may help from people to have a glance and close it because the reading is too tedious. Just a thought...

Comment: jarlh, thank you. 
 Fdavidov, it takes about 30s with my CONNECT BY clause. I am trying to optimalize this subquery which takes 2,5 sec for first 50 rows. List of Indexes I wrote below my questions.

Comment: As we have no information about the size of the tables, I would suggest (in blind) to try to use as 1st join conditions, those which filter the most the data used. On this way, the rest of the join conditions would spend less time for comparisons.

Comment: Please usin `JOIN` instead of 1990s style for joins. This is the first step to see better and optimize it.

Comment: OK, I added table rows count. Please advise.

Comment: The list of index columns is pretty much useless unless the information is added that tells us which column(s) belong to which index. Please **[edit]** your question and replace that list with the actual `create index` statements (do **not** post code in comments).